# Call oracle stored procedure from c# without knowing sp param name

Tags: c#, oracle

I'm expecting following code to run but it throws **Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter'**:

```
var conn = new OracleConnection(ORACLE_CONN_STR);
conn.Open();
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("procName", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("aParamValue");
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Why is there such an overload as OracleParameterCollection.Add(object) if I have to pass only OracleParameter?

Answer (score 0):

I thought OracleParameterCollection.Add(object) overload was there to supply parameter value without its name. The correct way of doing this is

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("", OracleDbType.Char).Value = "aParamValue";
```